# Random number with negative min or max and with 0.5 as possible decimal

Tags: java

So basically I need to generate a number between a min and max (could be negative as well) and there should be a possibility the number could end with a decimal 0.5.

So, for example, the numbers could be 5, 6, -8.5, 3.5.

I have this to generate my number (example):

```
rand.nextInt(20 + 1 + 10) - 10;
```

Comment: How about you generate an int with twice the range you want, and then divide it by 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could generate an integer with twice the range you want, and then halve it.

Something like this:

```
int min = -5;
int max = 15;
double r = min + 0.5 * rand.nextInt(2 * (max - min));
```

If you want `max` included in the random range, then:

```
double r = min + 0.5 * rand.nextInt(2 * (max + 1 - min));
```

Answer (score 0):

`Math.round((min + (rand.nextDouble() * Math.abs(max - min))) / 0.5) * 0.5;`

should do the trick by creating a correct value in range [min, max] (including both min and max as possible values!)